# include a document to the folder or in the folder

Tags: prepositions

I have attached a letter to the folder that I submitted or in the folder I submitted ?
Help please

Comment: Please see the [tag info for questions about prepositions](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/prepositions/info). Both of your variations are entirely grammatical, but they mean different things. You may need to describe exactly what you did with your letter and the folder in order that the right preposition can be determined.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with mauve127, but I think you have TWO problems!
1: is it 'to' or 'in'?
2: Have you submitted the folder or are you submitting it now, as you write this message?

I attached a letter to the folder I submitted.
Or
I have attached a letter to the folder I am submitting.
Or
I have enclosed/included a letter in the folder I am submitting.
Or
    I enclosed/included a letter in the folder I submitted.

Answer (score 0):

We generally "attach to", but "include in". If you letter is like a cover letter, it's probably better to say "attached to". But if your letter is going inside the folder, then you probably want to say "included in". Hope this helps!